# Serverworker seems to be making ajax requests extremely slow

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, service-worker

So I have a php app here with with a lot of JS making ajax requests back to the PHP to make DB requests. I'm in the process of adding a serviceworker, primarily to cache things and enable push notifications, however these ajax requests are taking up to 3-4 sometimes 5 seconds to return.

I've run the same requests directly in mysql and in phpmyadmin and they return in 0.000081 seconds, for example. So I'm not sure what could be causing this delay..

The database is relatively simple, 5-6 tables. One table has about 10 columns and 120 rows, the rest only have 3-4 columns with 50-60 rows. The database in on localhost (defined as 127.0.0.1 in config) and I've already added indexes on all fields where JOINs or WHEREs are done.

Some example code:

Ajax Request:

```js
    var dCIDQ = $("#company").val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api?aedCIDc='+dCIDQ
        }).then(function (data) {
        $('.dcid3').select2({
            multiple: true,
            placeholder: 'Select CID',
            data: data,
            debug: true
        });
        });

        $('.company').select2();
    });
```

PHP:

```php
if (isset($_GET['aedCIDc'])) {

    /*****************************************
     * Add Edit - Get derenCID options
     *****************************************/

    $dCIDcompany = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle, $_GET['aedCIDc']);

    $dCIDcompanyArray = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT  lieferantCID.id as id, \
lieferantCID.derenCID as text FROM lieferantCID LEFT JOIN companies ON \
lieferantCID.lieferant = companies.id WHERE lieferantCID.lieferant LIKE \
'$dCIDcompany'") or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

    while($resultsrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $dCIDcompanyArray[] = $resultsrows;
    }

    echo json_encode($dCIDcompanyArray);

  }
```

Serviceworker Fetch:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
     if ((/js$/.test(event.request.url)) || \
(/css$/.test(event.request.url)) || (/jpg$/.test(event.request.url)) || \
(/png$/.test(event.request.url)) || (/svg$/.test(event.request.url)) || \
(/svg$/.test(event.request.url)) || (/woff2$/.test(event.request.url))) { 
      // stale while revalidate
      event.respondWith(
        caches.open(RUNTIME).then(function(cache) {
          return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
              cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
              return networkResponse;
            })
            return response || fetchPromise;
          })
        })
      );
    } 
    else {
      event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
      return;
    }
});
```

(line breaks in code added here just for readability)

^^ I just want to stale while revalidate the static assets (im still in development and these do change pretty often atm) and fetch the rest straight from network.

Any idea whats going on?

EDIT: Heres an example network timeline:

[image: chrome devtool screenshot]

EDIT: So I removed the serviceworker, and copied the MySQL reponse into the PHP as a hard coded variable and just returned that, and the timing was still bad.. about 2-4 seconds to return that request. Wtf.

EDIT: So this gets stranger and stranger.. I've learned about the performance api and set some measurement marks. I set the start in the ajax call on beforeSend and then the end mark immediately after the entire ajax block, this came back as taking 0.4ms. I also set another set of marks around the entire script where the two ajax calls on my index page are, which also includes some math and initialising chart.js charts. This entire script takes ~400ms on average to run.

So I am now even more baffled as to how it takes 2-4 seconds to "finish" the call and display the charts, indicated by the "waiting" timer in chrome dev tools.

Comment: Could you share the `network timeline` for the service worker request?

Comment: EDIT: Added the image in the original post

Comment: `waiting` usually indicates a slow server or slow connection (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/issues#slow-ttfb) with the server. Have you tested the performance of the `api`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so normally I'd just delete this - but I figured I'd post my solution here for others who may be struggling with similar issues.

So of course it wasn't actually ajax or mysql having issues.. it was simply another bit of my code I was loading before making these requests. I found it by enabling the php-fpm slowlog and watching that. It can be enabled (in Ubuntu / Debian based distros) under `/etc/php/[version number]/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.